# Firefox: keep 2 versions, one with firebug addon enabled, one without

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I would like to have 2 versions / shortcut of Firefox, one with firebug (and other developer addons), and one for normal navigation (keeping bookmarks, history etc and some other addons like flashblock).
Is there a way I can do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several Options:

1. Using [VM's](http://www.vmware.com/)
2. [virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4580)
3. Interesting [article on "How to"](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2249039)
4. As well as [mozilla themselves](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/939994)

If using VM's I'd keep the most actively used version on main box, and VM / Virtual PC 
the others